nginx loadbalancer Host header
I am building a nginx loadbalancer where this is the current config:
upstream solrnodes {
        least_conn;
        server node01.cluster.solr.example.com:8983;
        server node02.cluster.solr.example.com:8983;
        server node03.cluster.solr.example.com:8983;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluster.solr.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cluster.solr.example.com/privkey.pem;

        server_name cluster.solr.example.com;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://solrnodes;
                proxy_ssl_name $proxy_host;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
}

However when testing it, error log says that in the request to the upstream server the Host is for some reason set to solrnodes:
"GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: solrnodes
X-Real-IP: 1.2.3.4
X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Priority: u=0, i
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

I want to set the SNI in the request to the the upstream adress.
Where is the mistake in my config?

You'll have to use "fake" server blocks https://stackoverflow.com/a/66867196/1016033
